# How to monitor aws lambda function memory usage with Datadog

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, out-of-memory, monitor, datadog

I need to monitor AWS lambda function memory usage and set alert rule about when memory usage reach to 80%, datadog sent alert. I have no idea how to do it.

At aws, we can use cloudwatch log to monitor memory usage, however, datadog is a different tool. Is it possible to use datadog to track memory usage?

Answer (score 0):

yes its possible , when you integrate datadog to your aws account , refer here: https://docs.datadoghq.com/getting_started/integrations/aws/ . Once successfully integrated , datadog should pull metrics from cloudwatch ( that means most of metrics avaiable in cloudwatch should be available in datadog ) and i see from datadog documentation they do emit lambda function memory usage, you can read more here: https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/monitoring-aws-lambda-with-datadog/

once you have metrics in datadog, you can basically create any kind of monitor/alerts, please refer this : https://docs.datadoghq.com/monitors/